# selenium, please help me about if

Tags: selenium

Use : Chrome, selenium.

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath('AAA') == False:
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "BBB"))).click()
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "CCC"))).click()
if driver.find_element_by_xpath('AAA') == True:
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "CCC"))).click()
```

*How can i do this?*

1. When I can't see AAA, I should click BBB button.
2. When I can see AAA, I must not to click BBB button.
3. When I can see AAA + click BBB button, I can't see AAA.

Comment: Please pick a title that summarizes your problem.

Comment: please also add the language in the tag and format the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('AAA')
 if not len(elem): 

     WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "BBB"))).click() 
     WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "CCC"))).click()

 else:

     WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "CCC"))).click()
```

find element doesn't return true or false , use find_elements intead and check the length . if length is not zero then element exists. so `not len(elem)` checks it doesn't exist meaning false

Comment: Please accept vthe answer by clicking the tick sign